# Filter rows by Nth column with R data.table fread in Windows

Tags: r, windows, csv, cmd, data.table

I have a large dataset which I would like to preprocess by filtering only some rows with the `cmd`argument. Unfortunately the original file has the filtering info on the third column and not the first.

I get it to work with this, but it is too slow:

```
fread(cmd='findstr /r "^.*,.*,4[0-9]," data.csv')
```

How to do this effectively, preferably so that findstr or equivalent would only start reading from the 3rd column onwards?

Here is the full MWE.

```r
library(data.table)
library(reprex)
library(rstudioapi)
library(styler)
#> Warning: package 'styler' was built under R version 4.2.3

data <- data.frame(
  "A" = c(11, 33, 34, 11),
  "B" = c("aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"),
  "C" = c(13,45,46,57),
  "D" = c(1,2,3,4)
)

# Writing data to a CSV file
write.csv(data, "data.csv",row.names=FALSE)

#whole file
fread("data.csv")
#>     A   B  C D
#> 1: 11 aaa 13 1
#> 2: 33 bbb 45 2
#> 3: 34 ccc 46 3
#> 4: 11 ddd 57 4

#filter based on first column(ok)
fread(cmd='findstr /r "^3[0-9]" data.csv')
#>    V1  V2 V3 V4
#> 1: 33 bbb 45  2
#> 2: 34 ccc 46  3

#filter based on third column but reads the first two columns as well (works as intended, but too slow)
fread(cmd='findstr /r "^.*,.*,4[0-9]," data.csv')
#>    V1  V2 V3 V4
#> 1: 33 bbb 45  2
#> 2: 34 ccc 46  3

#filter based on third column (does not work)
#fread(cmd='for /f "tokens=3 delims=," %i in (findstr /r "4[0-9]" data.csv) do echo %i')

# in cmd, this would print the numbers 45,46 as seperate outputs - and not return the filtered csv
#for /f "tokens=3 delims=," %i in ('findstr /r "4[0-9]" data.csv') do echo %i
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: What does "large"  mean? What does "too slow" mean?

Comment: Large means around 30 datasets with around 7million rows in each. I could narrow down to about 500K rows in each dataset so should save a lot of RAM. Reading one such dataset with `fread(realdata.csv)`took about 30sec and with the slow approach did not bother to wait after a couple of minutes: there is quite a bit of text before the third column.

Comment: And 30 seconds is too slow? I would just read the whole file and subset afterwards.

Comment: that is >=15 mins in total + taking RAM from other users. In any case, that is what I would do if I cannot find a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternate suggestion: use [`mlr`](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.11.0/), a command-line CSV utility.

Demonstration: I have a 2.2Mi row CSV with 57 columns (7 string, rest numeric). I want to filter on one column named `number`, keeping values that are equal to 22.

```r
library(data.table)
ps::ps_memory_info()["rss"] / 1024^2
#      rss 
# 75.64062 
Sys.which("mlr")
#            mlr 
# "/usr/bin/mlr" 
system.time(obj <- fread(cmd = "mlr --csv  filter '$number == 22' largedata.csv"))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  21.526   1.317  13.809 
dim(obj)
# [1] 64537    57
object.size(obj) # megabytes
# 29.3095 bytes
ps::ps_memory_info()["rss"] / 1024^2
#      rss 
# 114.8398
```

If I do the same thing using comparing

```r
read.csv("largedata.csv")
fread("largedata.csv")
arrow::read_csv_arrow("largedata.csv", as_data_frame=TRUE) # all data
arrow::read_csv_arrow("largedata.csv", as_data_frame=FALSE) |>
  filter(number == 22) |>
  collect()
# from @RuiBarradas
sqldf::read.csv.sql("largedata.csv", "select * from file where number=22")
```

The stats break out clearly in using `mlr`.

```
| Method                | Time   | Size      | RSS       |
|:----------------------|:-------|:----------|:----------|
| `read.csv`            | 73.767 | 1045.60MB | 2850.20MB |
| `fread`               |  3.085 | 1039.80MB | 1339.57MB |
| `arrow` true          |  3.559 |   29.32MB |  427.64MB |
| `arrow` false         | <2     |   29.31MB | 1460.91MB |
| `sqldf`               | 27.72  |   52.80MB |   91.75MB |
| `fread(cmd='mlr...')` | 13.8   |   29.31MB |  114.84MB |
```

Clearly the top 2 rows are "all data" and the bottom 4 rows are "3% of the data", so the object size is only a hint at the issue. RSS is a good indicator.

They have [binaries](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/releases), even for Windows.

(I included the `sqldf` suggestion in RuiBarradas's  answer, adapted to my larger data.)

---

*Below is the original answer using the `arrow` package.*

I don't know that you'll get a foolproof method that way using just `fread` (though I'm happy to be wrong here. However, an alternative would be to use `arrow::read_csv_arrow` in a "lazy" fashion along with `dplyr` verbs to subset your data. After it's in memory, you can use `as.data.table` as needed.

If you know the column name in question ahead of time, it is fairly direct:

```r
arr <- arrow::read_csv_arrow("data.csv", as_data_frame = FALSE)
arr |>
  filter(between(C, 40, 49)) |>
  collect()
# # A tibble: 2 × 4
#       A B         C     D
#   <int> <chr> <int> <int>
# 1    33 bbb      45     2
# 2    34 ccc      46     3
```

If you know it's the third field but that's all, we can use some "programming with dplyr" here:

```r
fld3 <- as.symbol(names(arr)[3])
arr |>
  filter(between(!!fld3, 40, 49)) |>
  collect()
# # A tibble: 2 × 4
#       A B         C     D
#   <int> <chr> <int> <int>
# 1    33 bbb      45     2
# 2    34 ccc      46     3
```

Not all R expressions can be executed, but many simple functions and logical filtering can be done quickly.

Note that while the `arr` object

```r
arr
# Table
# 4 rows x 4 columns
# $A <int64>
# $B <string>
# $C <int64>
# $D <int64>
```

makes no suggestion that any of the *data* has been loaded into memory, just some of the "meta" about the file. For instance, you can see that it "knows" which are strings, which are integers, etc. It remains "lazy" until you `collect()` it in the end.

Look at https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/dataset.html for some walk-through on the capabilities, and https://arrow.apache.org/docs/dev/r/reference/acero.html for a good list of supported R functions.

Comment: I will need to be using `data.table` for performance reasons. Also `arr <- arrow::read_csv_arrow` already takes n(0) and loads the whole dataset in memory, and we do not want that. The same should be accomplished faster with `dt <- fread(data.csv)` and then `dt[c %between% list(40, 49) ]`. Would like `fread` to already skip some lines with cmd.

Comment: (1) `read_csv_arrow(.., as_data_frame = FALSE)` does not load the whole dataset in memory. Heck, even with this paltry 4-row example, the `arr` object is 488 bytes and the real CSV loaded into memory is 1392. What makes you think that it loads all of it? (2) You want `data.table` for performance reasons, I totally get it (and I use it every day). There are certainly examples where `fread` may be faster at getting _certain types_ of data into memory, but those tend to be oriented around large strings. Otherwise, once it's in memory, `as.data.table` costs very little, and you're now running.

Comment: I stand corrected ... I just repeated this experiment several times using base, `data.table`, and `read_csv_arrow` (with both true/false as frame arg), and the RSS (resident set size, a measure of RAM used for a process) technically grows to the full size, but it is far faster. I'm going to guess that the data is loaded into memory space that R is not directly accessing. The numbers are lower, but not by much. I'm shocked because I regularly work with larger-than-memory datasets using arrow and do not exhaust my memory. Odd, head-scratcher.

Comment: @SamuelSaari see my edit for the suggested use of `mlr`.

Comment: Huge thanks, and my mistake for the most part. I can confirm that the arrow was indeed fastest, but not much compared with fread also with the real life dataset I am using. They both used similar amounts of memory, `arrow` as slightly better in that regard As dplyr functions in general, it probably creates a copy of the tibble somewhere. I cannot utilize `mlr` as I am not allowed to install any external software. However, `arrow` and `fread` are some much faster than `mlr` that I would have stuck with them anyway. A bit pity that there does not seem to be a fast and memory efficient solution.

Comment: @SamuelSaari Can you install `Rtools` on your machine? It contains many useful linux utilities such as `awk` that is helpful in this case. Try `Sys.which("awk")` to check if you already have it.

Comment: @SamuelSaari I see you came back to the question. Does `mlr` work well for you? I'm curious since I don't use it on a regular basis and am curious (professionally) if it handles the scale you need.

Answer (score 2):

With package [`sqldf`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=sqldf) you can filter with a SQL `SELECT` statement.

```r
library(sqldf)
#> Loading required package: gsubfn
#> Loading required package: proto
#> Loading required package: RSQLite

data <- data.frame(
  "A" = c(11, 33, 34, 11),
  "B" = c("aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"),
  "C" = c(13,45,46,57),
  "D" = c(1,2,3,4)
)

# Writing data to a CSV file
write.csv(data, "data.csv",row.names=FALSE)
rm(data)

sql <- "select * from file where C between 40 and 49"
read.csv.sql("data.csv", sql)
#>    A     B  C D
#> 1 33 "bbb" 45 2
#> 2 34 "ccc" 46 3

# or simply
sqldf::read.csv.sql("data.csv", "select * from file where C between 40 and 49")
#>    A     B  C D
#> 1 33 "bbb" 45 2
#> 2 34 "ccc" 46 3
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>